# XML Schema to validate element with any name and having nested elements with any name and restricted attribute value

Tags: xml, xsd

Given XML data:

```
<MyRootNode>
  <NodeY>
    <MyYNode Category="SomeCategory" />
    <AnotherYNode Category="AnotherCategory" />
    <YetAnotherYNode Category="NodeX" />
  </NodeY>
  <NodeX>
    <MyXNode Category="SomeCategory" />
    <AnotherXNode Category="AnotherCategory" />
    <YetAnotherXNode Category="NodeY" />
  </NodeX>
</MyRootNode>
```

I want to define XML schema that implies:

- `MyRootNode` is a fixed name
- `NodeY` and `NodeX` etc. are variable/any names for 1<sup>st</sup>-level nested elements
- `MyYNode`, `AnotherYNode`, `MyXNode` and `AnotherXNode` etc. are also variable/any names for 2<sup>nd</sup>-level nested elements
- Value of attribute `Category` in 2<sup>nd</sup>-level elements is one of `SomeCategory`, `AnotherCategory`, `NodeX` OR `NodeY`, but cannot have recursive reference within the element, e.g. under `NodeX`, there cannot be a node with `<Name>.Category` having value `NodeX` itself, but can have `NodeY` or any other 1<sup>st</sup>-level node name.

I attempted with:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="CategoryTypes" final="restriction" >
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="SomeCategory" />
      <xs:enumeration value="AnotherCategory" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="MyRootNode">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="???" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="???" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="CategoryTypes" name="Category"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

but not sure how to make the names variable value of `???` and include 1<sup>st</sup>-level node names in CategoryTypes.